# Maximal number of cubes in a given pyramid

Tags: optimization, 3d, volume, packing-problem

I have a pyramid whose base is a square of side length $a=120$, and whose height is also $a=120$. The projection of the summit of the pyramid on the square basis coincides with the center of the square (regular pyramid)

> What is the maximal number of cubes of side length $L=5$ that we can have inside the pyramid?

I have no idea how to start. Should I try some "greedy" algorithm? Is there any smart idea to solve this problem?

Any hint would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Pure volume considerations give us a trivial upper bound $\frac{120^3}{3}/5^3 = 4608$. Stacking cubes in $23$ layers with $k^2$ cubes in $k^{th}$ layer give us a trivial lower bound $\sum_{k=1}^{23} k^2 = 4324$. No idea about the actual maximum number. In general, optimal packing of geometric shapes inside a given container is a hard problem.

Answer (score 3):

If the base is $120 \times 120$ units, and the height is $120$ units, with the summit directly above the center of the base, then each side has a slope of $2$: one unit towards the center, the side wall rises by two units.

This means that at height $5$ above the base, each side is $5\times\frac{1}{2}=2.5$ inwards, i.e. $115\times 115$ in area, because each of the four sides (north, south, east west) is inwards by that amount. In other words, the bottommost layer of $5 \times 5 \times 5$ blocks covers $115 \times 115$ unit area of the base, and thus consists of $23 \times 23$ blocks.

The next layer of blocks is similarly smaller, covering a $110\times 110$ area on top of the previous layer of blocks, i.e. one block less in both directions, consisting of $22 \times 22$ blocks. (You might note that the center of each block in the upper layer is at the corners of four blocks in the lower layer, although it does not affect the math here at all.)

This continues upwards, with the 23rd layer having just one block. Note that since $23\times 5 = 115$, the summit of the pyramid (a rectangular pyramid itself, of course, with base $5\times 5$ on top of the topmost block, and height another $5$) is empty; it does not have enough room to contain even a single block.

If we count the number of blocks in each layer, we get
$$N = 23 \times 23 + 22 \times 22 + 21 \times 21 + \ldots + 1$$
That is not too hard to do by hand (or, better, calculator; or even with 2×2 Lego bricks),
but mathematically we can also say that
$$N = \sum_{i=1}^{23} i^2$$
As it happens, it is already known (in lists of known sums) that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 = \frac{1}{6} n (n + 1) (2 n + 1)$$
and therefore
$$N = \frac{1}{6} \times 23 \times 24 \times 47 = 4324$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look at it. But are you sure that the $N=4324$ is _the_ maximum? Isn't this a lower bound, as said achille hui in the comments? We could imagine some additional cubes that are not necessarily horizontal, for instance. You can have a look to the case $n=10$ in the $2$-dimensional situation [here](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/squintri/), to see better what I mean.

Comment: @Alphonse: No, I am not sure it is the true maximum. But this is the way you can calculate the low bound for the maximum without any particular prior math skills -- you don't even need the series, as you can certainly calculate a sum of 23 squares. On the other hand, the unpopulated pieces are all either quarter of a full block volume (on the sides), or one twelfth of a full block volume (on the four corners); the final top missing piece being one third of a full block volume. There is much less "room" for non-rectangular positioning compared to most other cases, like the cases you linked to.

Comment: That is, I would be surprised to find out there actually is a more dense packing for such a right rectangular pyramid. It is already very dense; this case the simple method achieves a relative density of $4324/4608 \approx 93.8\%$. 3D packings with cubes are much harder than 2D with squares; unaligned orientations cause much bigger losses (unused volumes). On the gripping hand, I'm often wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can calculate the volume of the pyramid and then divide it by the volume of the cubes:

The volume of the pyramid is $V=a^2\frac{h}{3}$ or in this case $V = 120^2\frac{120}{3}$ or $5.76 \times 10^5$ (yay calculators).

The volume of the cubes would be $V = b \cdot h \cdot w$ or in this case $V = 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 = 5^3$ which equals $125$.

Then, $\frac {5.76 \times 10^5}{125} = 4608$ (again, yay calculators!) meaning, of course, that you can fit 4608 cubes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But the cubes can't go outside the pyramid, I'm not sure that your method works. It would work if the pyramid was replaced by a big cube, for instance.

Comment: @Alphonse, I understand what you're saying, but I think the method works (though it would be really hard to get them all to fit properly). You can angle the cubes just so to fit them into the corners and get creative about it. Also, if this *isn't* correct (though I think it is) I really don't see how you are supposed to do it. What level of math are you in?

Comment: Ok… I don't know. I think this problem could be solved without any particular mathematical knowledge. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Alphonse, what I mean is, I think the alternate solution (if there is one) would be so complicated that it wouldn't make sense for them to assume you knew about it.